# Grouping data by weeks Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a result from a query with the following columns.
Name, Value , Location , date
I want to have two more column with start date and end date .The start date is Friday of the week and end date is next Thursday. week starts from 07/19/2013.I want to group the date column.
i tried using WITH clause to generate the weeks,but I have to make a Cartesian join and the connection breaks.

```
  WITH Q1 AS
( SELECT dates AS start_date , dates + 6 AS end_date FROM
        (SELECT DATE '2013-07-18' + LEVEL-1  dates FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (TRUNC(SYSDATE)- DATE '2013-07-18'))
     WHERE TO_CHAR( dates,'DY') = 'FRI'
)
Select q1.Start_date, q1.end_date, t.name, t.value, t.date
from test1 t,Q1
where date between q1.start_date and Q1.end_date;
```

I have exadata on which this Cartesian join works all fine,but not on other database.

The output should be

```
Start date End date    Name  value   Date
---------- --------    ----  -----   -------- 
07/19/2013 07/25/2013   A       5      07/22/2013
07/19/2013 07/25/2013   b       3      07/23/2013
07/26/2013 08/01/2013   c       6      08/01/2013
08/02/2013 08/08/2013   A       2      08/06/2013
---
--
-- 
11/29/2013 12/05/2013   t       5      12/01/2013
11/29/2013 12/05/2013   s       3      12/02/2013
11/29/2013 12/05/2013   t       5      12/02/2013
```

Comment: Not sure why you think you need a cartesian join.  In pseudo-sql: `select previous_sunday(date), following_saturday(date), date, name, value,location from...` where `previous_sunday(date)` and `following_saturday(date)` are expressions that calculate the start and end dates.

Comment: @jimgarrison ,I updated my question to answer your Cartesian join doubt.I want to write in a different way.Somehow i am getting ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel, But when I run other queries or anything else it runs perfectly fine, which says it has to do something with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRUNC(date, 'IW') does the trick - finds the first day of the week. Then it is just arithmetic.

```
select to_date('07/18/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') + rownum cur_date,
       TRUNC((to_date('07/18/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') + rownum) - 4, 'IW') + 4 as start_date,
       TRUNC((to_date('07/18/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') + rownum) + 3, 'IW') + 3 as end_date
  from dual connect by level <= 100;

CUR_DATE    START_DATE  END_DATE
-------------------------------------
19-JUL-13   19-JUL-13   25-JUL-13
20-JUL-13   19-JUL-13   25-JUL-13
21-JUL-13   19-JUL-13   25-JUL-13
22-JUL-13   19-JUL-13   25-JUL-13
23-JUL-13   19-JUL-13   25-JUL-13
24-JUL-13   19-JUL-13   25-JUL-13
25-JUL-13   19-JUL-13   25-JUL-13
26-JUL-13   26-JUL-13   01-AUG-13
27-JUL-13   26-JUL-13   01-AUG-13
28-JUL-13   26-JUL-13   01-AUG-13
29-JUL-13   26-JUL-13   01-AUG-13
30-JUL-13   26-JUL-13   01-AUG-13
31-JUL-13   26-JUL-13   01-AUG-13
01-AUG-13   26-JUL-13   01-AUG-13
```